# Contribution vs Motivation

Tags: publications, terminology

Can somebody explain to me what is the difference between contribution and motivation in any research paper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Motivation**: why is this an important problem? Why should anybody care about this?

For example:

> X affects tens of thousands of consumers in the United States each year, and costs companies billions of dollars.

or

> If we can solve X, we are one step closer to solving the biggest open problem in the field, Z.

**Contribution**: what is the new thing (result, approach, technique, whatever) that this paper describes, that advances the state of this field?

For example:

> This paper describes a way to do X using Y, which is up to 200 times faster than the current state of the art.

Comment: Can we then say motivation describes the problem statement?

Comment: @user2999915 A problem statement could just be "Here is a problem X." That's not really motivation, unless you say "We really want to know how to do X because [insert motivation here]..."

Comment: @Mike Problem statement = "This is the problem we want to solve". Problem motivation = "The problem is relevant, because many people need to do X", contribution = "We solve these aspects of the problem".